# "convert myself to mathematics"

Tags: expressions

Does "convert myself to mathematics" make sense? For example,

> My major was not mathematics. I study very hard to **convert myself to mathematics**.

What would you say instead?

Thanks!

Comment: I would say that you **changed your major to mathematics**, not that you converted. The word _converted_ is often used for a change in religious affiliations, as in: _He converted to Islam, but his sister converted to Judaism._

Comment: Thanks! But I can't change my major, so I have to convert myself to math.

Comment: Oh! _Mea culpa_; I misread your opening sentence. I see what you mean now. This is a very good question. Perhaps: _"My major was not mathematics. I studies very hard to convert myself **into a mathematician**."_ When used like this, the verb _convert_ is almost a humorous. I'm looking forward to seeing what others have to say about this one

Comment: ("studied" surely?)  I like "convert myself into a mathematician" as well.  One converts oneself *into* something that defines the self in a new way; one converts *to* something that one begins to use--anything from a new religion to a new brand of soap.

Comment: I can see a strong similarity with how we say it in Italian. What about this other expression: I had to reinvent myself as a mathematician ?

Answer (score 1):

The word "convert" is usually used when speaking of altering a mechanical device, like "We converted the garbage disposal unit into a computer"; or to describe a change in religion or philosophy, like "Charlie converted to Mormonism" or "We are trying to convince people to convert to Republicans".

As JR says, you could say that you are "trying to convert myself into a mathematician" as a metaphor for the first type of conversion, or "trying to convert myself to mathematics" as a metaphor for the second. Few would consider it appropriate to take it literally.

In any case, the more conventional phrasing would be to say, "I am trying to make myself a mathematician" or "I am trying to learn mathematics" or "I am trying to become a mathematician". No doubt many other possible wordings.